# Network script doesn't work. CentOS 2.6

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

Centos 2.6.32-179.9.1.el6.i686

Hello, I have a problem with my noowbie script.
It does not work.
When I try to use it (for ex., /etc/init.d/myscript start) nothing happened.
Before that I make chkconfig --add myscript and chmod 777 on it.
Can you help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
#chkconfig: 2345 10 90
#description test

. /etc/init.d/functions

if [ ! -f /etc/sysconfig/network ]; then
    exit 0
fi

. /etc/sysconfig/network

if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 ]; then
    . /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1
fi

[ "${NETWORKING}"="no" ] && exit 0
[ -x -a /sbin/ifconfig ] || exit 1

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "started"
        ifconfig eth1 ${IPADDR} netmask ${NETMASK} up
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "stopping"
        ifconfig eth1 ${IPADDR} netmask ${NETMASK} down
        echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        ;;
    status)
        echo "showing status"
        ifconfig
        cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        route -n
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
[ -x -a /sbin/ifconfig ] || exit 1
```

is a syntax error, and you should get a diagnostic from `bash` when you try to run the script. Assuming something in `/etc/init.d/functions`, `/etc/sysconfig/network`, or  `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` hasn't already caused your script to terminate, that line will.

And, actually, isn't `/etc/sysconfig/network` usually a directory? If so, this will cause your script to just exit, since it's not a file:

```
if [ ! -f /etc/sysconfig/network ]; then
  exit 0
fi
```

Edit: You might want to change the first line of your script to `#!/bin/bash -x` to aid in debugging. That will show you a trace of what it's doing as it runs.

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/network is a file where is variable NETWORKING=yes (or no) exists. It is a default centos construction if I understand correctly.

Comment: Ok, that's why I asked - I'm not familiar with CentOS, and on some distros, that's actually a directory that contains other things...

Comment: Well, about what syntax error you have talked about? P.S. /etc/init.d/functions it is centos system lib with shell functions. /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 is a file with configuration of eh1 interface. I made it manually.

Comment: `[ -x -a <filename> ]` is wrong - the `<filename>` is extra there, because `-x` only takes one argument, and `test`/`[` will consider the extra word to be a syntax error. You probably meant `[ -x <filename> ]`.

Comment: Amemendment to above comment - now that I've actually tested it, it seems `bash` at least doesn't throw an error on that construct like `ksh` does, but the meaning doesn't appear to be what you would think either... It appears to mean "if (length('-x') > 0) and (length('/sbin/ifconfig') > 0)".

Comment: [ -x -a /sbin/ifconfig ] || exit 1 is logically wrong, I see. I have removed that string, but nothing happend. Now I think maybe I have problems with eth interface, not with script.

Comment: Hmmm. It was something wrong with [ "${NETWORKING}"="no" ] && exit 0. Without that script is working correctly. But i dont know what is wrong. In /etc/sysconfig/network i have string NETWORKING=yes. So in script I cheking if there is yes or no.

Comment: Ah... didn't notice that line earlier. Put spaces around the `=`, like this: `[ "${NETWORKING}" = "no" ]`. It's interpreting that as "if length('yes=no') > 0", which is always true, and so it exits.